# I receive errors with my F# implementation of SimpleClusterListener

Tags: f#, akka.net, akka.net-cluster

I have observed the following error on my F# implementation of SimpleClusterListener:

> [ERROR][3/20/2017 11:32:53 AM][Thread
>   0008][[akka://ClusterSystem/system/endpoin
>   tManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FClusterSystem%400.0.0.0%3A2552-
>   5/endpointWriter#1522364225]] Dropping message
>   [Akka.Actor.ActorSelectionMessage ] for non-local recipient
>   [[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:2552/]] arriving at
>   [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:2552] inbound addresses
>   [akka.tcp://Clust erSystem@0.0.0.0:2552]

I ran the C# implementation (referenced in the Appendix below) with no issues. In addition, I am using the same ports that the C# implementation is using.

**NOTE:**

I'm new to Akka.Net and as a result, am struggling to troubleshoot where I went wrong with the example I attempted to port.

My implementation is as follows:

**Main.fs**

```
module Program

open System
open System.Configuration
open Akka.Configuration.Hocon
open Akka.Configuration
open Akka.Actor
open Samples.Cluster.Simple

[<Literal>]
let ExitWithSuccess = 0

let createActor port =
    let section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection "akka" :?> AkkaConfigurationSection
    let config =  ConfigurationFactory.ParseString("akka.remote.dot-netty.tcp.port=" + port)
                    .WithFallback(section.AkkaConfig) 
    let system = ActorSystem.Create ("ClusterSystem", config)
    let actorRef = Props.Create(typeof<SimpleClusterListener>)
    system.ActorOf(actorRef, "clusterListener") |> ignore

let startUp (ports:string list) = ports |> List.iter createActor

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    startUp ["2551"; "2552"; "0"]
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit")
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    ExitWithSuccess
```

**SimpleClusterListener.fs**

```
namespace Samples.Cluster.Simple

open Akka.Actor
open Akka.Cluster
open Akka.Event

type SimpleClusterListener() =

    inherit UntypedActor()

        override this.PreStart() =
            let cluster = Cluster.Get(UntypedActor.Context.System)
            let (events:System.Type array) = [| typeof<ClusterEvent.IMemberEvent>
                                                typeof<ClusterEvent.UnreachableMember> |]
            cluster.Subscribe(base.Self, ClusterEvent.InitialStateAsEvents, events)

        override this.OnReceive(message:obj) =

            let log = UntypedActor.Context.GetLogger()

            match message with
            | :? ClusterEvent.MemberUp          as e -> log.Info("Member is up: {0}",                   e.Member)
            | :? ClusterEvent.UnreachableMember as e -> log.Info("Member detected as unreachable: {0}", e.Member)
            | :? ClusterEvent.MemberRemoved     as e -> log.Info("Member is removed: {0}",              e.Member)
            | _ -> ()

        override this.PostStop() = 
            let cluster = Akka.Cluster.Cluster.Get(UntypedActor.Context.System)
            cluster.Unsubscribe base.Self
```

The OnReceive method above never gets invoked. However, the PreStart method does.

**Appendix:**

As stated earlier, I ported the C# implementation below. I successfully ran this code. Thus, I am confused as to where I went wrong when I attempted to port it.

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="Program.cs" company="Akka.NET Project">
//     Copyright (C) 2009-2016 Lightbend Inc. <http://www.lightbend.com>
//     Copyright (C) 2013-2016 Akka.NET project <https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net>
// </copyright>
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

using Akka.Actor;
using Akka.Configuration;
using Akka.Configuration.Hocon;
using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Samples.Cluster.Simple
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StartUp(args.Length == 0 ? new String[] { "2551", "2552", "0" } : args);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void StartUp(string[] ports)
        {
            var section = (AkkaConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("akka");
            foreach (var port in ports)
            {
                //Override the configuration of the port
                var config =
                    ConfigurationFactory.ParseString("akka.remote.dot-netty.tcp.port=" + port)
                        .WithFallback(section.AkkaConfig);

                //create an Akka system
                var system = ActorSystem.Create("ClusterSystem", config);

                //create an actor that handles cluster domain events
                system.ActorOf(Props.Create(typeof(SimpleClusterListener)), "clusterListener");
            }
        }
    }
}



//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="SimpleClusterListener.cs" company="Akka.NET Project">
//     Copyright (C) 2009-2016 Lightbend Inc. <http://www.lightbend.com>
//     Copyright (C) 2013-2016 Akka.NET project <https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net>
// </copyright>
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

using Akka.Actor;
using Akka.Cluster;
using Akka.Event;

namespace Samples.Cluster.Simple
{
    public class SimpleClusterListener : UntypedActor
    {
        protected ILoggingAdapter Log = Context.GetLogger();
        protected Akka.Cluster.Cluster Cluster = Akka.Cluster.Cluster.Get(Context.System);

        /// <summary>
        /// Need to subscribe to cluster changes
        /// </summary>
        protected override void PreStart() =>
            Cluster.Subscribe(Self, ClusterEvent.InitialStateAsEvents, new[] { typeof(ClusterEvent.IMemberEvent), typeof(ClusterEvent.UnreachableMember) });

        /// <summary>
        /// Re-subscribe on restart
        /// </summary>
        protected override void PostStop() => Cluster.Unsubscribe(Self);

        protected override void OnReceive(object message)
        {
            var up = message as ClusterEvent.MemberUp;
            if (up != null)
            {
                var mem = up;
                Log.Info("Member is Up: {0}", mem.Member);
            }
            else if (message is ClusterEvent.UnreachableMember)
            {
                var unreachable = (ClusterEvent.UnreachableMember)message;
                Log.Info("Member detected as unreachable: {0}", unreachable.Member);
            }
            else if (message is ClusterEvent.MemberRemoved)
            {
                var removed = (ClusterEvent.MemberRemoved)message;
                Log.Info("Member is Removed: {0}", removed.Member);
            }
            else if (message is ClusterEvent.IMemberEvent)
            {
                //IGNORE                
            }
            else if (message is ClusterEvent.CurrentClusterState)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                Unhandled(message);
            }
        }
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="akka" type="Akka.Configuration.Hocon.AkkaConfigurationSection, Akka"/>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
  </startup>
  <akka>
    <hocon>
      <![CDATA[
          akka {
            actor {
              provider = "Akka.Cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider, Akka.Cluster"
            }

            remote {
              log-remote-lifecycle-events = DEBUG
              dot-netty.tcp {
                hostname = "localhost"
                port = 0
              }
            }

            cluster {
              seed-nodes = [
                "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:2551",
                "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:2552"]

              #auto-down-unreachable-after = 30s
            }
          }
      ]]>
    </hocon>
  </akka>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I see you are referencing dot-netty in your config. Are you using the latest dev?

Comment: I created a new C# console app with copy/paste code and I'm observing the same exact issue as my F# implementation. Therefore, there's something behind the scenes that I'm not aware of that's causing an issue.

Comment: No you misunderstand. Which version of Akka.net are you using? Are you using the 1.1.3 packages?

Comment: The version is 1.1.3.31

Comment: I added the config file to the appendix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your using the 1.1.3 packages. 
You should use

```
ConfigurationFactory.ParseString("akka.remote.helios.tcp.port=" + port)
                    .WithFallback(section.AkkaConfig);`
```

And not the `dot-netty` transport. That one is not released by us yet. And is only available in the dev branch.

Comment: I get several errors in the output window when making an update based on your suggestion.

Comment: [ERROR][3/20/2017 6:23:10 PM][Thread 0028][[akka://ClusterSystem/system/endpoint
Manager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FClusterSystem%400.0.0.0%3A2551-5
/endpointWriter#1544393941]] Dropping message [Akka.Actor.ActorSelectionMessage]
 for non-local recipient [[akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:2552/]] arriving a
t [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@localhost:2552] inbound addresses [akka.tcp://Cluste
rSystem@0.0.0.0:2552]
Cause: Unknown